# Not able to Debug MicroService running inside docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

i am trying to debug the application https://github.com/sqshq/piggymetrics, which when ran through docker compose will run inside docker container, i am trying to debug the application the IDE which i am using is intellij IDEA and environment in which docker is running is ubuntu, i am getting "unable to open debugger port handshake failed"

### to run the application

just set the environment variables as mentioned https://github.com/sqshq/piggymetrics#before-you-start
and after the application starts using docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up just go to localhost:8761(Eureka server) and open the url mentioned adjacent to application GATEWAY  and remove the /actuator/info from the url ,the application will be running at 172.18.0.14(ip assigned at my system ):4000

> My approach to debug the application:-
> i have set breakpoints in account-service on createNewAccount method AccountController.class and , i tried to create new account from application, hoping to hit the method and then i configured intellij to listen to remote on the same port on which account-service is running, the debugger starts listening on the port after few minutes i am getting "unable to open debugger port handshake failed " and my debug points are not hit

i even tried to configure debugger on different port like this https://blog.docker.com/2017/05/spring-boot-development-docker/ ,but still out of luck

Docker file for account-service looks like below

```
FROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER Alexander Lukyanchikov <sqshq@sqshq.com>
ADD ./target/account-service.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=6000","-Xmx200m", "-jar", "/app/account-service.jar"]
 
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS="6000"
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
 
EXPOSE 6000
```

Comment: Can you run the application outside of Docker, and debug it there?

Comment: no i didn't tried , because i have to change lot of configurations and start manually all applications, but i think i would be able to debug the application